# LDAP extension for dokuwiki

Tags: ldap, dokuwiki

I am trying to allow authentication against my ldap server, but everytime when I turn on the LDAP extension I got following error

> LDAP err: PHP LDAP extension not found. [auth.php:34] User
>   authentication is temporarily unavailable. If this situation persists,
>   please inform your Wiki Admin.

I have set up everything necessary in Configuration Manager.

Any suggestions that can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need the PHP LDAP extension. You can probably install it via your distribution's package manager. Eg. apt-get install php5-ldap